# why the label "p" don't slide down when i click the button "hide" or "show"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click the button hide or show ,the label "p"  don't slide down.But when the function is fadeToggle it can run. How can i let the label "p" slide down when i click hide or show?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jquery</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("button").click
                (   function ()
                    {
                       // $("p").fadeToggle("slow");
                       // $("p").fadeTo("slow");
                        $("p").slideDown("slow");

                    }
                );
            }
        );

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1">hello show and hide</p>
    <button type="button">hide</button>
    <button type="button">show</button>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `p` tag hidden onload and then when any button i.e : hide/show is clicked check if it has a particular class depending on this `slideDown` or `slideUp` your `p` tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  //check if the button has show class..
  $(this).hasClass("show") ? $("p").slideDown("slow") : $("p").slideUp("slow");
});
```

```css
p#p1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">hello show and hide</p>
<!--added hide/show class-->
<button type="button" class='hide'>hide</button>
<button type="button" class='show'>show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `#p1` should be hidden before it can slide down. Please check my code below

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      // $("p").fadeToggle("slow");
      // $("p").fadeTo("slow");
      $("p").slideDown("slow");

    });
  }
);
```

```css
#p1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jquery</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="p1">hello show and hide</p>
  <button type="button">hide</button>
  <button type="button">show</button>
</body>

</html>
```